# How to select Excel PivotTable report layout using python and win32com?

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table, win32com

How do I select the report layout of a Excel PivotTable using win32com specifically the "Show in Tabular Form"?

In excel I will select the, PivotTable > Design tab > Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form:

[image: Excel PivotTable Report Layout]

Example code to create PivotTable

```
Excel   = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') # Excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
win32c = win32com.client.constants

wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add()
Sheet1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

TestData = [['Country','Name','Gender','Sign','Amount'],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Plus',123.4567],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Minus',-23.4567],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Plus',12.2314],
             ['CH','Max' ,'M','Minus',-2.2314],
             ['CH','Sam' ,'M','Plus',453.7685],
             ['CH','Sam' ,'M','Minus',-53.7685],
             ['CH','Sara','F','Plus',777.666],
             ['CH','Sara','F','Minus',-77.666],
             ['DE','Hans','M','Plus',345.088],
             ['DE','Hans','M','Minus',-45.088],
             ['DE','Paul','M','Plus',222.455],
             ['DE','Paul','M','Minus',-22.455]]

for i, TestDataRow in enumerate(TestData):
    for j, TestDataItem in enumerate(TestDataRow):
        Sheet1.Cells(i+2,j+4).Value = TestDataItem

cl1 = Sheet1.Cells(2,4)
cl2 = Sheet1.Cells(2+len(TestData)-1,4+len(TestData[0])-1)
PivotSourceRange = Sheet1.Range(cl1,cl2)

PivotSourceRange.Select()

add = wb.Sheets.Add()
add.Name = "Sheet2"

Sheet2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
cl3=Sheet2.Cells(4,1)
PivotTargetRange=  Sheet2.Range(cl3,cl3)
PivotTableName = 'ReportPivotTable'

PivotCache = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=PivotSourceRange, Version=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTable = PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=PivotTargetRange, TableName=PivotTableName, DefaultVersion=win32c.xlPivotTableVersion14)

PivotTable.PivotFields('Name').Orientation = win32c.xlRowField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Name').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('Gender').Orientation = win32c.xlPageField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Gender').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('Gender').CurrentPage = 'M'
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').Position = 1
PivotTable.PivotFields('Country').Subtotals = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
PivotTable.PivotFields('Sign').Orientation = win32c.xlColumnField
PivotTable.PivotFields('Sign').Position = 2

DataField = PivotTable.AddDataField(PivotTable.PivotFields('Amount'))

Excel.Visible = 1
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro in Excel to see what it is happening when you use the menus?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.rowaxislayout   So `PivotTable.RowAxisLayout(win32c.xlTabularRow)` I suppose.